# attribute defined outside __init__ with class and sub class

Tags: python

According to this link:
[Python class: How to check whether an attribute is defined inside __init__ or outside __init__](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48578627/python-class-how-to-check-whether-an-attribute-is-defined-inside-init-or-ou)
I should define all my attributes with **init**.

However,  I still get the pylint warning that " **attribute 'real' is defined outside **init****' but it is defined in the subclass constructor....

Is the warning still valid and if so what is the recommendation to fix it?
The warning comes from code analysis in spyder.
Yes, the code works but I would like to improve my programming by removing this if it is a valid warning.

```
class mainclass():
'''main class'''

    class subclass:
        '''subclass'''
        def __init__(self, real=None):
            ''' subclass constructor'''
            self.real = real

    def __init__(self, var1):
        '''main class construcor'''
        self.A = {1: self.subclass(), 2: self.subclass()}
    
#...ommited irrelevent code
```

Comment: Your code works for me:  a = mainclass.subclass(23)
a.real
Out[35]: 23

Comment: This code works for me. How do you get the warning?

Comment: @Swifty I don't think the question is "does it work". I think the question is "is this going to cause problems in future when you extend it". Personally I think it's fine and just a linter misfiring, but I haven't really thought it through

Comment: Though if you want var1 to be passed to the "children" like this: a=mainclass(23) ; a.A[1].real ; 23 , you need to add it as arguments in your self.A definition. (@DavidW I meant works without any warning, should have been more clear :) )